# Como obtener la dirección MAC en sistemas Windows con el lenguaje C

Tags: c, windows

Quiero saber como obtener la dirección MAC en sistemas Windows con el lenguaje C. He visto ejemplos pero están en el sistema operativo Linux. Les agradceria mucho si alguien sabe como obtenerla en sistemas con Windows.

Gracias.

Comment: Puedes usar [GetAdaptersInfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13646621/how-to-get-mac-address-in-windows-with-c).

Answer (score 0):

no se si es de la forma que tú la quieres, pero podría ser de la siguiente.

```c
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    system("getmac");
    return 0;
}
```

La librería `stdlib.h` contiene la función `system()` que permite utilizar comando propios del sistema, por ello utilizando el comando **getmac** en su interior se pueden obtener las mac.